# Why is the bottom tab navigator height smaller (squished) upon reload?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working with the `createBottomTabNavigator()` from React Navigation in my Expo application. I have 3 different tabs for different screen routing. Each tab consists of the screen name and an icon.

However, I am experiencing some inconsistent behavior after I reload the screen using expo. On the home screen load, the height of the bottom tab navigator appears to be "squished".

**Squished Behavior:** Notice in the picture below that the icons are to the left of the text and how thin the navigation bar is. [image]

**Normal Behavior:** Now notice the "regular" behavior once I double click the home button or do some action to refresh the screen.

[image]

I can even navigate through the 3 navigation pages and it will stay in this "squished" state until I do something like double click home button (on iPhone this brings up your open applications - similar to the bottom right square Android button).

The code for the bottom tab navigation is below. There isn't anything fancy with it, just pretty standard stuff from the documentation.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeTab = createStackNavigator();
const UserProfileTab = createStackNavigator();
const NutritionTab = createStackNavigator();

function UserProfileScreen() {
  return (
    <UserProfileTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Colors.topNavBar
        },
        headerTitleAlign: 'center'
      }}>
      <UserProfileTab.Screen name="Profile" component={UserProfile} />
    </UserProfileTab.Navigator>
  );
}

function NutritionScreen() {
  return (
    <NutritionTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Colors.topNavBar
        },
        headerTitleAlign: 'center'
      }}>
      <NutritionTab.Screen name="Nutrition" component={Nutrition} />
    </NutritionTab.Navigator>
  );
}

function BottomTabs() {
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: Colors.topNavBar }} />
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.topNavBar }}>
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Home"
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;

              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home';
              } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
                iconName = focused ? 'user' : 'user';
              } else if (route.name === 'Nutrition') {
                iconName = focused ? 'md-nutrition' : 'md-nutrition';
              }

              if (route.name === 'Nutrition') {
                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
              }
              return <AntDesign name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
          })}
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: Colors.bottomNavBarActive,
            inactiveTintColor: Colors.bottomNavBarInactive,
            tabStyle: styles.tabStyle,
            labelStyle: styles.tabLabel,
          }}>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Nutrition"
            component={NutritionScreen}
            options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Nutrition' }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={MainStackNavigator}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={UserProfileScreen}
            options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Profile' }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  )
}

// Styling
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.boxColor,
  },
  tabLabel: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Has anyone ever faced an issue like this? Is it just some weird glitch with Expo?

Comment: Having same issue, have you found the way to fix this? It just magically happened to me since maybe after installed 1 of `expo-application`, `expo-firebase-analytics`, `expo-secure-store`, but not exactly sure which

Comment: No, unfortunately I never found a solution. It was very intermittent and I couldn't pinpoint when or why it would happen.

Comment: I filed a bug in [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9562) but no reply yet. Doesn't seems to happen often, only when rapidly reload or something